# How to Install Public Keys with GPG

Tags: openpgp

I am installing vagrant and I am trying to follow their instructions. My next step is to install their PGP public key. I'm on Windows so it's not as easy as just --recv-keys, I need to place this code somewhere:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1
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=LYpS
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Does anyone know where I should? I'm using GnuPG - not any of the bloatware in Gpg4win.

Answer (score 9):

If you already successfully installed GnuPG -- no matter whether you built the code on your own, only installed the small command line binary or a full distribution including a graphical user interface and client applications like GPG4Win -- run `gpg --import` to import keys into the GnuPG internal keyring. Store the public key informaiton into a file, which you then import (there are other ways, but let's stick to the one canonical method to import keys). You can call it in different ways on the command line, either by passing a file name to import (first example), or by piping the file's contents into GnuPG (second example):

```
gpg --import publickey.gpg
gpg --import < publickey.gpg
```

In the end, graphical user interfaces do the exactly same thing and run GnuPG behind the scenes.

If you know a key ID or fingerprint, you can also use `gpg --recv-keys [keyid]` to fetch a key, for example

```
gpg --recv-keys a4ff2279
```

If there is no key server defined in your GnuPG configuration file, you can also pass one on the command line:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys a4ff2279
```

In the end, `--recv-keys` uses HTTP (or other protocols) to receive key information from the key servers, and then `--import`s this data.